# What's the best way for remote desktop control (100m away)?

Tags: wifi

I have two desktop computers with one located far away from the other. I want to use remote desktop control on pc1 to watch videos from pc2. Currently I use teamviewer via LAN(wifi), but it is unstable. Should I change my software or hardware? Can someone give me advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is 100m meters or miles? Remote connectivity is a terminal session. The remote computer passes keyboard/mouse and receives audio/video. There is compression and encryption involved which will introduce latency. Everything comes into play, not the engine used.

What else is running on the both systems?
Are apps updating?
Is AV scanning all traffic?
What are the types of connections, lease lines or broadband?
What are the upstream/downstream rates?
What else is on both networks?
How fast is the local interconnectivity?

The biggest difference between TeamViewer and RDP is TeamViewer shares the session, RDP takes it over. RDP will require opening up a port on the host side, default 3389 and forwarded to the system running the video. The OS of the host will need to support RDP, which home versions of the Windows OS do not. If the IP address is dynamic, it can change, so a reservation or static IP address is recommended.  You can also tune your IP settings to disable offloading.

With performance issues, you need to locate the bottleneck. Knowing the specifics of hardware, software, configuration and communications is key to getting the best results with what you have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

In reality you shouldn't be doing it at all, but I understand why you might want/need to do this.
There are so many interfering factors that make this remote desktop solution difficult: such as wifi/overall network performance, pc1 and pc2's performance, the software, etc.

Teamviewer is designed to make remote access smooth and easy, even on slow connections. You can adjust it's settings for better performance, but as a side effect of remote access, the video and audio will always be unstable for this purpose.

Other software such as Shayme27's recommendation may improve the experience. but remote access is built for remote management of a machine, not for media server/remote rendering functions. Try to avoid doing this, if you can.